# From a stack that contains 25 articles, 5 of them are defective, then we choose 4 at random.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I have the following problem;

From a stack that contains 25 articles, 5 of them are defective (20 are not), then we choose 4 at random. Let X be the number of defective articles founded.

Get the probability distribution of X if the articles were choosen whitout replacement.

I've already did the case when there is replacement (I use binomial probability function) but in this case the probability is not always the same, so I don't know what to do.

I will appreciate if you can give some hints please.

Comment: what about simply calculating the possible combinations? For example, $P(X=1)= 20C3 \times 5C1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The probability distribution you want is known as the Hypergeometric Distribution.

You have a population of size $N=25$ containing $K=5$ possible successes (the defective items are what we're counting), and the trials are $n=4$ draws without replacement.

Then you want to compare the count of ways to select $k$ of the $K$ successes, and $n-k$ of the $N-K$ failures, *against* the count of the ways to select any $n$ of all $N$ items.